# Do $.getJSON and continue to navigate to link href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am taking a click event on an anchor with JQuery which makes a $.getJSON request to the server sending some data in the querystring. I am doing some logic in the server with the querystring provided and returning nothing back to the client. 
I am not making e.preventDefault(); on the click; so after the javascript code runs it will go immediately to navigate to another page.
my question is:  Is there any side effect to let this code runs like that?
Normally i would do:

```
e.preventDefault();
$.getJSON('uri', function(data){
location = $(this).href;
});
```

To navigate after the callback.

Comment: `href` is not a property of a jQuery object. You mean to use the prop() method.

Comment: Have you tested it in different browsers? There might be differences in how the requests and navigation are handled, so that some browsers won't make the AJAX call because the navigation happens first.

Comment: @charlietfl: Actually `this.href` won't work either, as `this` is no longer a reference to the element when the callback is called.

Comment: @charlietfl: No, the redirect is not in the callback. It's in the callback in the alternative code that the OP is showing, but not in the code that the question is about because then it would never happen.

Comment: browsers won't wait for ajax if don't prevent the default IMO...click event is synchronous

Comment: @charlietfl: No, it won't wait for the AJAX call to complete, but the question is whether it will reliably send the request.

Comment: As stated in the linked duplicate question, the behavior is unpredictable if you do not wait until the call has been made before proceeding with a location change.

Comment: Yes, href is not a property I meant to write location = $(this).attr('href'); but the question is willl the getJSON request be handled properly eventhough I navigate quick to the other page?

Comment: Looking in the net. I believe my goal can be achieved by using a var img = new Image() and settings its src to my end point....looks promising. thanks everyone.